# SharePoint 2010 record center delete corrupt document set

Tags: sharepoint-2010, center, record, document-set

I'm using SharePoint 2010 Record Center to hold Document Sets. These Document Sets are send here from different SharePoint libraries. The Document Sets are send to specific libraries using the drop off library and rules. The Document Sets expire after some time. We use a Custom Expiration Formula and the Expiration Policy to delete expired document sets.

One of these Document Sets (actually more than 10000) contains a corrupted file.

This file is shown as a record,  but can be checked out and edited. But when i want to check it in again i receive an error "this file is marked as read-only". All other files in the Document Sets act as records, No alteration is possible.

- the file cannot be deleted from Record Center
- the file cannot be deleted using Explorer view (webdav)
- the user deleting the file is site collection admin (has full control)

**Question:**
How can i delete this specific file or Document Set (over 10.000 times)

Comment: did you ever find a resolution for this? I'm having the issue where a file is corrupted doesn't become a record properly.